# If statement won't continue

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I am trying to do some computations on VB.net. I used `if else` statement since I'm a bit familiar with it. My code goes like this

```
 Try
        Dim a As Integer = msalary.Text
        If (a < 9000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 200
        ElseIf (9000 < a < 9999.99) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 225
        ElseIf (10000 < a < 10999.99) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 250
        ElseIf (11000 <= a < 11999.99) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 275
        ElseIf (12000 <= a < 12999.99) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 300
        ElseIf (13000 <= a < 14000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 325
        ElseIf (14000 <= a < 15000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 350
        ElseIf (15000 <= a < 16000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 375
        ElseIf (17000 <= a < 18000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 400
        ElseIf (18000 <= a < 19000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 425
        ElseIf (19000 <= a < 20000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 450
        ElseIf (20000 <= a < 21000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 475
        ElseIf (21000 <= a < 22000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 500
        ElseIf (22000 <= a < 23000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 525
        ElseIf (23000 <= a < 24000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 550
        ElseIf (24000 <= a < 25000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 575
        ElseIf (25000 <= a < 26000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 600
        ElseIf (26000 <= a < 27000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 625
        ElseIf (27000 <= a < 28000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 650
        ElseIf (28000 <= a < 29000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 675
        ElseIf (29000 <= a < 30000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 700
        ElseIf (30000 <= a < 31000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 725
        ElseIf (31000 <= a < 32000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 750
        ElseIf (32000 <= a < 33000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 800
        ElseIf (33000 <= a < 34000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 825
        ElseIf (34000 <= a < 35000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 850
        ElseIf (a >= 35000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 875
        ElseIf a = "" Then

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The farthest the condition was able to go to -225 even if I put 20000 in it. It will only subtract 225 from the 20000. Is there something wrong on what I did or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing some `AndAlso` from your `If/ElseIf` statements.  Normally, you wouldn't be able to go from String to Integer without doing a conversion, so I'm guessing you don't have `Option Strict`

```
Try
        Dim a As Integer = msalary.Text
        If (a < 9000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 200
        ElseIf (9000 <= a AndAlso a < 10000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 225
        ElseIf (10000 <= a AndAlso a < 11000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 250
        ElseIf (11000 <= a AndAlso a < 12000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 275
        ElseIf (12000 <= a AndAlso a 13000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 300
        ElseIf (13000 <= a AndAlso a < 14000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 325
        ElseIf (14000 <= a AndAlso a < 15000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 350
        ElseIf (15000 <= a AndAlso a < 16000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 375
        ElseIf (17000 <= a AndAlso a < 18000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 400
        ElseIf (18000 <= a AndAlso a < 19000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 425
        ElseIf (19000 <= a AndAlso a < 20000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 450
        ElseIf (20000 <= a AndAlso a < 21000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 475
        ElseIf (21000 <= a AndAlso a < 22000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 500
        ElseIf (22000 <= a AndAlso a < 23000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 525
        ElseIf (23000 <= a AndAlso a < 24000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 550
        ElseIf (24000 <= a AndAlso a < 25000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 575
        ElseIf (25000 <= a AndAlso a < 26000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 600
        ElseIf (26000 <= a AndAlso a < 27000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 625
        ElseIf (27000 <= a AndAlso a < 28000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 650
        ElseIf (28000 <= a AndAlso a < 29000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 675
        ElseIf (29000 <= a AndAlso a < 30000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 700
        ElseIf (30000 <= a AndAlso a < 31000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 725
        ElseIf (31000 <= a AndAlso a < 32000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 750
        ElseIf (32000 <= a AndAlso a < 33000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 800
        ElseIf (33000 <= a AndAlso a < 34000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 825
        ElseIf (34000 <= a AndAlso a < 35000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 850
        ElseIf (a >= 35000) Then
            Label5.Text = a - 875
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: hello. i am having this error message everytime i clear or erase the numbers on my textbox for "a"..it says `Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.`..any idea on what to do?

Comment: Add an if statement that checks that the textbox is not empty

Comment: worked..i tried it earlier. gues i placed it the place..thanks

Comment: This is missing a case for 16k to 17k

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use such a giant conditional branch, I'd find a more algorithmic approach.

Example:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim salary As Integer = 34567, subtractor As Integer = 200
        Dim r As Range = GetSalaryRange(salary)
        For I As Integer = 9000 To r.Lower Step 1000
            subtractor += 25
        Next
        Label5.Text = (salary - subtractor).ToString
    End Sub
    Function GetSalaryRange(salary As Integer) As Range
        If salary < 9000 Then Return New Range() With {.Lower = 0, .Upper = 8999}
        Dim remainder As Integer = salary Mod 1000
        Return New Range With {.Lower = salary - remainder, .Upper = salary - remainder + 999}
    End Function
    Public Class Range
        Public Lower, Upper As Integer
        Public Function Contains(number As Integer) As Boolean
            If number >= Lower AndAlso number <= Upper Then Return True Else Return False
        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```